# Windows Vms are unable to connect to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

The Windows VMS connected earlier to Jenkins as an agent are in offline now and unable to connect again  with error "port:49187 is not reachable".

```
Feb 20, 2024 6:02:46 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using C:\Jenkins\remoting as a remoting work directory
Both error and output logs will be printed to C:\Jenkins\remoting
Feb 20, 2024 6:02:46 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up agent: DPVMNLDEV1
Feb 20, 2024 6:02:46 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
Feb 20, 2024 6:02:46 PM hudson.remoting.Engine startEngine
INFO: Using Remoting version: 3.29
Feb 20, 2024 6:02:46 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using C:\Jenkins\remoting as a remoting work directory
Feb 20, 2024 6:02:47 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [
https://jenkins.devops.com/

Feb 20, 2024 6:02:47 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver resolve
INFO: Remoting server accepts the following protocols: [JNLP4-connect, Ping, JNLP3-connect]
Feb 20, 2024 6:02:52 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver isPortVisible
WARNING: connect timed out
Feb 20, 2024 6:02:52 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver resolve
INFO: Remoting server accepts the following protocols: [JNLP4-connect, Ping, JNLP3-connect]
Feb 20, 2024 6:02:53 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver isPortVisible
WARNING: Connection refused: connect
Feb 20, 2024 6:02:53 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE:
https://jenkins.devops.com/
provided port:49187 is not reachable
java.io.IOException:
https://jenkins.devops.com/
provided port:49187 is not reachable
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.resolve(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:287)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:523)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:474)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException:
https://jenkins.devops/com:8080/
provided port:49187 is not reachable
                ... 3 more
```

We have checked with network and infosec team, no changes from their end and no changes made in Jenkins or Windows VMs recently .

Can anyone had this issue or help here .